# How to set dotnet function version similar to dotnet web app assembly version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, function, azure-functions

I have a dotnet function app and trying to set the assembly version similar to the dotnet web app. But when I try to read the assembly version I am only receiving the dotnet function runtime version. I need a way to set the version of the function app in build time and read that during runtime time.

```
dotnet publish -c Release -p:UseAppHost=false -o buildFolder project.csproj
```

with the above publish command I want to pass a version number and I should be able to read the version in runtime

Even if I add Assembly version like this in the visual studio
[image]
[image]

But the api is returning the core tools versions only not the assembly version as expected
[image]

I am able to do that in a dotnet web app with the below command

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o buildFolder project.csproj -p:Version=$(version)
```

and I am reading like this

```
string version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

I want similar thing in dotnet function app

Answer (score 0):

> I want similar thing in dotnet function app

To set dotnet function version which is similar to dotnet webapp use below code, it displays `function app version` instead of `function runtime version`.

**Function.cs:**

```cs
public static class VersionFunction
{
    [FunctionName("GetVersion")]
    public static string Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://ms.portal.azure.com");

        
        string version = GetAssemblyVersion();

        return $"Function App Version: {version}";
    }

    private static string GetAssemblyVersion()
    {
        Assembly entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        return entryAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

- The above code uses `GetAssemblyVersion()` to get the version as shown in the output below.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi as updated in the question the Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version is returning the Core Tools Version not the assembly version we are setting

Comment: As you can see in the above screenshot that I didn't get the Azure core tools version. I have got the assembly version only by using the function app. Once try with the given code above. This is my [runtime version](https://i.imgur.com/MO3tuam.png) and this is my [assembly version](https://i.imgur.com/RiwIYO7.png).

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: @RakeshT.R, please look into my above modified code, expected it may works.